# Perl regex add char before char

Tags: regex, perl

I need help with adding backslash before special chars.
Note: I cant use any module so I need to create simple script.

Let say u have line like this :

```
<link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
```

Now I would like to add "\" before any " or other special Perl chars like :

```
$%/!`|
```

At the end it should be:

```
<link class=\"include\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"../css/style.css\" />
```

I tried to use:

```
$line =~ s/["%'\/{|}]+/\\$1/g;
```

Didn't work.

What regexp should I use?

Comment: "didn't work" is a *very* bad way to describe your problem. There is hardly ever any situation when it is unwarranted to describe exactly what happened, or say that nothing happened.

Comment: This is also likely an XY-problem, and you're asking the wrong question here. Why do you need to escape those chars inside your string?

Comment: What do you mean by "special chars"?  Why are you doing this to the string?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You want to escape the forward slashes in `../css/style.css`?  Why?  Also, your "At the end it should be:" doesn't show it.

Comment: Well, thanks for justintime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting the special character to be available in `$1`. To do that you need to capture it using `(  )`

```
$line =~   s/ ( ["%'\/{|}] ) /\\$1/xg;
```

Note I have added some spacing and //x qualified to make the ( ) stand out better.

Another way is to use a forward lookahead.

```
$line =~ s/(?= [%'\/{|}] ) /\\/xg;
```

Comment: Sorry - I didn't quote the \ and stackoverflow was not displaying as expected. Is this any better.

Comment: removed the + that I had copied from the original question. This meant only the first of a sequence of special characers was escaped